# Page numbering. Empty pages for notes include in page numbering?

Tags: style, publishing, formatting, ebook, notes

I have a few questions about the page numbering of the last few pages of my book.

1. I have a section with further resources. It contains one page with information about a site and three more pages with site links and organizations. Which pages should be numbered, which not?
2. The next section is for notes. Its first page simply has 'NOTES' printed as a title and followed by three empty pages. Which pages should be numbered, which not? In some other books I've noticed the author did not title the page 'NOTES' and as a result didn't number the page. Since I'm also publishing it as an ebook, it feels that people who print the book may feel there's a problem if they just see 4 empty pages.

What's the best practice?

Answer (score 2):

I would number the first section of references with lowercase Roman numbers; i,ii,iii,iv.

I did not realize "NOTES" meant My notes, so if I saw four blank pages titled NOTES I would suspect a problem. I have read non-fiction books that include ***Author*** notes under a section called NOTES, numbered again with Roman numerals, beginning again with 'i'. If you intend this as some kind of text book, I would title it "Reader Notes" or "Your Notes" or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

There are no universal rules.

If your organisation has a style of its own, follow that.

Otherwise, go to any library or bookshop and look closely at however many books it takes to show clearly how others have already done it.